# Cygwin compile error: "log10l" not recognized (declared)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, cygwin

I am compiling a linux program on cygwin (teaching a class with students that have windows computers) and have run into a problem with compatibility I think.

The error I get is this:

```
`$ Make
g++ -fopenmp -c start.cpp errors.cpp
start.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
start.cpp:1184:54: error: ‘log10l’ was not declared in this scope
         else po[i]=log10l(p_rj[i]/(1-p_rj[i]));
                                                  ^
Makefile:7: recipe for target 'start.o' failed
Make: *** [start.o] Error 1`
```

The log10l is not declared. A little research on cygwin's site about this and I found this [page](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-api/std-notimpl.html) which lists "non implemented system interfaces" and log10l is on there.

Do I need to replace 'log10l' with a compatible function and  why would't it be compatible?

App compiles without error on my linux box.

Any Help would be much appreciated.

LP

Comment: I believe that log10l is the c99 standard. in c++ simply use log10 (there are overloads for double and long double)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that function is just taking the log base 10 of the inner expression, you can just replace it with

```
else po[i] = std::log10(p_rj[i]/(1-p_rj[i]));
```

As long as you

```
#include <cmath>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked- atleast the compile finished. I had to change logl to log as well. More broadly, why does CygWin not recognize those functions? Are they not  c++ functions? I dont program in c++ so less familiar... is log10l different from log10?

Comment: I think that `log10l` comes from `<math.h>`, it is the `long` version of `log10`, rather than the templated C++ standard one.

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin does not currently support `long double` math functions, of which `log10l` is one.  You can use `log10` instead, but it is limited to a `double` type.